# Ctrl key sticking a lot seems to be logically stuck

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

Hi I am having a HP ab125ax laptop.
*hardware spec:
processor: a10-8700p,
GPU:r7 m360,
Logitech mk220 combo wireless combo keyboard mouse*

**Problem:** In live installation I have no issue with my keyboard mouse(done lots of web browsing ) but after install on OS its seems all most all time <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key press so while mouse scrolling its zoom-in/out typing in Firefox its activated its bookmark history open file etc(activate all shortcut key which use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> like typing d its active <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> which open bookmark option) .

**Actions taken:**

1) remove battery from key board but still scroll in with mouse zoom in and out. and other function

2) Remove mouse also by detach the USB receiver problem almost solve but not totally while scrolling using touch pad its still zoom in and zoom out and also the bookmark option and other thing also happen but its less than before like 5-7 time in 1/min.
OS: problem happen in Ubuntu 16.04 Linux mint 18 fedora 24 problem happen in every OS but in windows 10 everything is OK.

p.s:Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having this issue too.  What helped me is: go to system settings, then universal access, and then turn off repeat keys or change the delay.